# jQuery highlight clickable areas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to ask you if there is a way of highlighting clickable items within a basic HTML page, ideally by pressing a keyboard key.
When I build functional prototypes, to save time only some of the functionality is actually developed to show the flow. I want to somehow show which items are clickable, so users don't need to hover every single item to find out what can be clicked.

Ideally what I want to achieve is when a user presses a predefined key, a box appears on top of every link (text or image or map coordinates), and this should be achieved automatically via a script, so that I don't have to set it up manually for every prototype I build.

Is that possible to achieve? Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do it like this:

Assign a CSS class (i.e. `highlight_class`) to all clickable elements. Use jquery to handle the key event and hightlight all matching element like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 32){ //Space key
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.highlight_class').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    }        
});
```

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52EC4/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It works great on plain text links, however if I want to link an image or a map area, the highlight does not show. Maybe I have to try different types of highlighting? Also is there a way for the trigger to work differently, so that the highlights are shown while the key is being held down, instead of doing a show/hide with timeout? That way if you hold down the key for 5 seconds, you have time to see all the different areas that are clickable.

Comment: I think for images you have to create your own highlight function. (i.e. change the opacity of the image). If you like to to show the highlight while a key is being held down, you can use the `keydown()` event to enable the highlight and the `keyup()` event to disable it.

Comment: yeh maybe I will have to somehow let the function create a new div above the area and assign some color to it so it looks as an highlight. Because it might be only a small portion of a large image that is actually clickable, not always the whole image...

Comment: Sorry to dig this one up but I was wondering if you could help me figure out how to use the keydown/keyup so that I can highlight items while pressing the key, and the highlight is fully on until the key is released. I'm just unsure of how to stop the highlight when the key is released instead of a preset 3 second delay. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the key you want to trigger a function using jQuery [keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

For example, you can create add hidden divs to your markup and when the user press that key the display is toggled.

You can also achieve it using keycode. For example

```
 var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
 if(code == 9) { //keycode for the tab key
   $(".hidden-elements").toggle();
 }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery's .keypress()

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

An idea can be to add a css class to your clickable items. You can then loop through the elements with that class, and pop up some tooltip, since you know your item and can determine its position.

However, wouldn't it be better to highlight with some light colour your clickable rows? Or perhaps adding a small icon, to let the user know at first glance what can he do?